# database query's columnCount() and getColumnMeta() missing from core

Tags: database, 10

In Drupal 9 I could do:

```php
$result = \Drupal::database()->query($query, $args);
```

then call

```php
$result->columnCount()
```

also

```php
$recs->getColumnMeta($c)
```

In Drupal 10 these functions: `columnCount()` and `getColumnMeta($c)` do not exist on the `\Drupal\Core\Database\StatementWrapperIterator` object returned ([core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/StatementWrapperIterator.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.2.4/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/StatementWrapperIterator.php?ref_type=tags)) - or elsewhere in core.

What is best way to get this data?

### Update

If I add to core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/StatementWrapperIterator.php

```php
  public function getColumnMeta($idx) {
    return $this->clientStatement->getColumnMeta($idx);
  }

  public function columnCount() {
    return $this->clientStatement->columnCount();
  }
```

- all seems fine. Not sure if this is correct approach so figured out using getClientStatement() to get PDO functions that are missing from Drupal's wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear these were part of core in Drupal 9 either: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/9/search/getColumnMeta

These appear to be PHP PDO functions:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php

And they still appear to exist.

Comment: Yes digging deeper I realised that. However I get: Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Database\StatementWrapperIterator::columnCount()  which did not use to happen.  I'd also tried the code example in the php.net with same result, so class structure has changed somehow

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you had a custom patch in your D9 site, because even the predecessor ([`StatementWrapper`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21StatementWrapper.php/class/StatementWrapper/10.0.x)) didn't have the methods you mention.

You shouldn't patch the core class to combat this, instead you should retrieve the `PDOStatement` from the wrapper, and call the method(s) on that:

```
$result = \Drupal::database()->query($query, $args);
$column_count = $result->getClientStatement()->columnCount();
```

Comment: There were no core patches but I guess something was providing the wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!